# Data changing between calls in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I made a little change to Tensorflow MNIST tutorial. 
Original code (fully_connected_feed.py, lines 194-202):

```
checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.log_dir, 'model.ckpt')
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=global_step)
#Evaluate against the training set.
print('Training Data Eval:')
do_eval(sess, 
        eval_correct, 
        images_placeholder,
        labels_placeholder,
        data_sets.train)
```

I simply added one more evaluation:

```
checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.log_dir, 'model.ckpt')
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_file, global_step=global_step)
print('Something strange:')
do_eval(sess, eval_correct, images_placeholder,labels_placeholder,
        data_sets.train)
#Evaluate against the training set.
print('Training Data Eval:')
do_eval(sess, 
        eval_correct, 
        images_placeholder,
        labels_placeholder,
        data_sets.train)
```

Results of this evaluations are close, **but not same** (numbers vary from launch to launch):

```
Something strange:
  Num examples: 55000  Num correct: 49218  Precision @ 1: 0.8949
Training Data Eval:
  Num examples: 55000  Num correct: 49324  Precision @ 1: 0.8968
```

How does it possible?
UPD: added link to tensorflow github:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist

Comment: No idea about tensorflow, but this should not happen generally. Does do_eval have unintended side effects? Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: I don't know where those side effect could come from. do_eval code have only call to evaluation() method from mnist.py, and that method do not make changes to any tensors.

Comment: Seems pretty weird. I'm not very familiar with tensorflow specifically, but I don't see in which way this could be deemed sane behavior (I guess do_eval should just forward pass the samples and calculate the precision on it without changing the net).

Comment: I haven't spent much time with TF, but is there a certain random state parameter that changes between `do_eval` calls?

Comment: MNIST is probably solved with a feed forward net that does not have a state, although I just am doing educated guessing. :) At least I never saw anyone applying RNNs to MNIST.

Comment: As I know, only random parameters are init values of weights and biases -- so, it does not change between two calls. And it is feed forward net -- no recursive connection.

Comment: It doesn't seem like they're using dropout, either (even though the [tutorial does do so](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/#densely_connected_layer)); I originally thought this might be a misinitialization of the dropout probability.

Comment: Ah, so it retrains every time? Then it is of course not unusual to end up with different precision values. Due to different weight initialization the training can very well end up in different local minima each time and I would actually expect it to do so in most cases.  With deep learning you usually just do not need to care as they are all mostly pretty good solutions. Fix the random number generator to a specific seed before each call to do_eval, if you want to check for reproducibility.

Comment: You can generally expect in deep networks that your local minima are all not far from the global one. I have no rigorous mathematical proof for it, but I would say especially with high dimensionality in deep nets you will always hit different local minima whenever you train and you will notice at most a tiny difference in accuracy. That is what I got from Bengio's discussion regarding SGD on the manifolds minimized by deep nets and practical experience. Cf: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203288/understanding-almost-all-local-minimum-have-very-similar-function-value-to-the

Comment: Martin Kramer, I understand it. But as you see, there are two evals one after other, and no training or reinitializing between them. So, numbers have to match exactly (I don't mean match from one launch to another).
And I can even disable training -- don't call this op or return zero gradients -- and this effect will remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `do_eval()` function in fact does have a side effect, because `data_sets.train` is a [stateful `DataSet` object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/624861052f70f6b07c1f714352f0bf7092ea237f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L103) that contains a current `_index_in_epoch` member, which is advanced on each call to [`DataSet.next_batch()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/624861052f70f6b07c1f714352f0bf7092ea237f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160) (i.e. in [`fill_feed_dict()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/624861052f70f6b07c1f714352f0bf7092ea237f/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py#L78)).

On its own, this fact shouldn't be enough to give non-deterministic results, but there are two other details about `DataSet.next_batch()` that lead to the non-determinism:

1. Every time a new epoch is started, the examples are [randomly shuffled](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/624861052f70f6b07c1f714352f0bf7092ea237f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L178).
2. When the data set [reaches the end of an epoch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/624861052f70f6b07c1f714352f0bf7092ea237f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L173), the data set resets to the start and the last `num_examples % batch_size` examples are discarded. Thanks to the random shuffling, a random sub-batch of examples is discarded each time, leading to the non-deterministic results.

Given the way the code is structured (with the `DataSet` shared between training and testing), it's tricky to make the code deterministic.
The `DataSet` class is sparsely documented, but this behavior is surprising, so I'd consider [filing a GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) about this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I found a way to make calculations deterministic -- just set batch_size equal to number of examples in dataset. Of cause, it's useful only for debugging.